# Cmake configuration for multiple sub-libraries in a "packages" directory

Tags: c++, cmake

[Here](https://github.com/ShahOdin/SampleCpp/) is a sample project I am trying to build with a "Packages" directory which includes all the libraries to be used in the main code.

I am trying to keep my root cmake file as clean as possible and avoid relative path such as

```
include_directory(packages/lib1)
```

but I am struggling. Is there a way of including sub-directories of a directory for the purposes of header inclusion.

Comment: Please show what you have tried to achieve your goal. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: It's a mixture of add_subdirectory,  include_directory etc. But I keep getting errors. I have already seen the tutorial which covers the case of adding libraries in individual directories. It's putting them all in another directory that causes problems.

Comment: @Torbjörn I don't understand the downvotes. I have a specific question about having a CMakeLists.txt including its sub libraries. I didn't want to clutter the question with a wall-text that is not relevant to the question here, but I have added my attempt at the problem.

Comment: Main part of project's structure should be **in the question post itself**, not *linked* to outer cite. Even with viewing repo, current revision of the question seems completely uncleared for me. Just a guess: Do you want/ would it be sufficient for you that tests can be added using two lines: `add_executable(test_target1 ...)` and `target_link_libraries(test_target1 lib1)`? (So the test needn't to `include_directories` at all, this would be done automatically.)

Answer (score 3):

First a few minor remarks:

- always name the CMake configuration files `CMakeLists.txt` ([because of](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#directories))
- bookmark the documentation on CMake: https://cmake.org/documentation/
  Sometimes it's not that easy to read, but very specific once you adopt your head to the "CMake world" ;-)
- make yourself comfortable with the [scope of CMake variables](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables)

[`include_directories(DIR1 [DIR2 [...]])`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/include_directories.html)
Tells CMake where the compiler should look for header files, i.e. `-IDIR1 -IDIR2 ...`.

[`add_library(NAME [STATIC|SHARED] SOURCES)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html)
This command creates the required compiler commands to create a static or shared library out of a given list of source files. No need to add in the header files. The make target will be called `NAME` and the library target is known to CMake as `NAME`.

[`add_subdirectory(DIR)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_subdirectory.html)
Tells CMake to look into `DIR` and parse the included `CMakeLists.txt` with all its content.

[`target_link_libraries(TARGET LIB1 [LIB2 [...]])`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html)
Tells CMake to instruct the linker to link `LIB1`, `LIB2`, etc. to the `TARGET`, i.e. `-LLIB1 -LLIB2 ...`. `TARGET` is a CMake/make target previously defined/created with a call to `add_{library,executable,custom_target}`.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
include_directories(libraries)
# a header file in `libraries/lib1/foo.hpp` can be included
# in the whole CMake project by `#include "lib1/foo.hpp"`.
add_subdirectory(libraries)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

**libraries/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
```

**libraries/lib1/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(lib1 STATIC ${LIB1_SOURCES})
```

**libraries/lib2/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${LIB2_SOURCES})
```

**tests/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(tests ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(tests lib1 lib2)
```

Comment: Thanks. I only named them CmakeLists1, etc. so I could reference them easier but I still managed to get them mixed up. Regardless, are you sure about your include_directories(libraries) in the root CmakeList.txt? Does it include all of its sub-directories too? Also, ideally I want my lib1, lib2 etc to have their own Cmake files, so prefer doing add_library(lib1 ... ) inside their respective cmake files (inside directory lib1, etc.) and only add-subdirectory(lib1) from the Libraries/CmakeLists.txt  if possible. What I am not sure about is where I should put my include()s.

Comment: I have updated my attempt. the include-directory in Libraries/CMakeLists.txt doesn't seem to get carried over though and a "global" include_directories(Libraries) in the root Cmake file doesn't work.

Comment: uploaded the project to github. hopefully that should make things easier.

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it more specific. Yes, the placement of `include_directories` is correct. Please reread the docs on `target_link_libraries`; only CMake/make targets can be used, no directory names.

Comment: Thanks. However I don't want to have to do " lib1/foo.hpp" in my includes. I have done some more research and came up with this new version of the code: https://github.com/ShahOdin/CmakeTest I do: include_directories (${lib1_SOURCE_DIR})
add_library(lib2 STATIC ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1) in my lib2's Cmake file. but I am getting errors. Any idea why it's not working as it should?

Comment: As long as you don't provide the kind of error, I've to scry my crystal ball. I'm not good at that. Usually, the errors are quite descriptive. In case they are compiler errors, make the makefile verbose by calling CMake with `-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON`. Then the full call to the compiler and linker are printed.

Comment: It gives me fatal error. No such file or directory. ie it fails to include it. I have asked it in a new question here if you want to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034904/cmakes-target-link-libraries-for-library-outside-current-directory