cmake linking libraries in sibling directories problem
I am using cmake for c++. The sample project I am working on looks like this:
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Lv1b
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── b.cpp
│   └── b.h
├── Lv1c
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Lv2c
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── c.cpp
│       ├── c.h
│       └── c_helper.cpp
├── Lv1test
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── test.cpp
├── a.cpp
├── a.h
├── cmake_tutorial.md
├── cmake_tutorial.txt
└── main.cpp

While I have succeeded linking libraries in subfolders without stating absolute nor relative paths onto the top CMakeLists.txt file, I am failing to include library targets from Lv1b and Lv1c/Lv2c into executable target in Lv1test.
This is my hardware/software:
- 2019 Macbook Pro 15 (x86)
- macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
- Homebrew clang version 18.1.6
- cmake version 3.9.
And these are my code&cmakelists that are probably relevant:
All of which are commented out are trials that didn't work.
#<./CMakeLists.txt>

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(OURPROJECT
        LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp a.h a.cpp)

add_subdirectory(Lv1b)
add_subdirectory(Lv1c)
#target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
#                            PUBLIC Lv1b Lv2c Lv1test)

add_subdirectory(Lv1test)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
                            PUBLIC Lv1b Lv2c )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
                            PRIVATE B_LIBRARY C_LIBRARY)
# target_link_libraries(TESTEXE PRIVATE B_LIBRARY C_LIBRARY)


/* <./main.cpp> */
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
int main () {
    afunction();
    bfunction();
    cfunction();
    return 0;
}

#<./Lv1b/CMakeLists.txt>
add_library(B_LIBRARY b.h b.cpp)

#<./Lv1c/CMakeLists.txt>
add_subdirectory(Lv2c)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
                            PRIVATE Lv2c)
# target_include_directories(TESTEXE PRIVATE Lv2c) #not working: Cannot specify include directories for target "TESTEXE" which is not built by this project.

#<./Lv2c/CMakeLists.txt>
add_library(C_LIBRARY c.h c.cpp c_helper.cpp)

#<./Lv1test/CMakeLists.txt>
add_executable(TESTEXE test.cpp)

target_include_directories(TESTEXE PUBLIC ../Lv1b ../Lv1c/Lv2c)

#target_include_directories(TESTEXE PUBLIC TestCmakeDir Lv1b Lv2c)
#target_include_directories(TESTEXE PUBLIC TestCmakeDir Lv1b Lv2c)
#target_link_directories(TESTEXE PRIVATE B_LIBRARY C_LIBRARY)

target_link_libraries(TESTEXE PRIVATE B_LIBRARY C_LIBRARY)

/* <./Lv1test/test.cpp> */
#include <iostream>
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"

int test () {
    std::cout << "testing library b" << std::endl;
    bfunction();
    std::cout << "testing library c" << std::endl;
    cfunction();
    return 0;
}

target_include_directories(TESTEXE PUBLIC ../Lv1b ../Lv1c/Lv2c) <<<< I tried to avoid explicitly writing directions(both relative and absolute path) because I was able to do so with linking ${PROJECT_NAME} with B_LIBRARY and C_LIBRARY so that I don't have to change the CMakeLists.txt that the file|library is made from regardless how many new folders are created between Lv1c and Lv2c.  However I gave up on doing so for this case but linking still fails:
Terminal.
% cmake -S . -B out/build -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: 
/Users/username/Code/cpp_tutorial/cmake_practice/TestCmakeDir/out/build

% make -C out/build 
[ 30%] Built target C_LIBRARY
[ 50%] Built target B_LIBRARY
[ 80%] Built target OURPROJECT
[ 90%] Building CXX object Lv1test/CMakeFiles/TESTEXE.dir/test.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable TESTEXE
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      <initial-undefines>
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [Lv1test/TESTEXE] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Lv1test/CMakeFiles/TESTEXE.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

When I DO NOT provide the relative path to <./Lv1test/CMakeLists.txt>, i.e.
target_include_directories(TESTEXE PUBLIC TestCmakeDir Lv1b Lv2c)

which works perfectly fine for linking libraries in nested sub-directories, I get the following error:
% make -C out/build
[ 30%] Built target C_LIBRARY
[ 50%] Built target B_LIBRARY
[ 80%] Built target OURPROJECT
[ 90%] Building CXX object Lv1test/CMakeFiles/TESTEXE.dir/test.cpp.o
/Users/username/Code/cpp_tutorial/cmake_practice/TestCmakeDir/Lv1test/test.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'b.h' file not found
    2 | #include "b.h"
      |          ^~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [Lv1test/CMakeFiles/TESTEXE.dir/test.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Lv1test/CMakeFiles/TESTEXE.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

So
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70971977/cmake-library-with-example-subdirectory-running-as-separate-project
do not work and also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999833/cmake-configuration-for-multiple-sub-libraries-in-a-packages-directory
doesn't work. Maybe it is a macos thing?
So now I don't know what to do now.
If there is an option, I would highly prefer the method where I do not need to directly locate the positions of directories|libraries, especially because I made it happen in the case of nested sub-libraries.
Thank you in advance.

Your TESTEXE executable doesn't define the function main. This is what the first error message is talking about. Linkage with the other libraries is irrelevant.

Can you explain a bit more about what it means to define function main? I'm new to cmake even though I have been hassling with it for a week now... You mean that I should include TESTEXE in main?

You are creating OURPROJECT executable from the main.cpp source file which defines the function main. But TESTEXE executable is created from the Lv1test/test.cpp source file, which doesn't defines main function. Exactly main function is called immediately after the executable is run.

Or you mean I should either change TESTEXE into a library or I need to have two main file and make the compiler switch which one to build depending on the situation as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919957/how-can-i-build-two-executables-that-share-a-main-function-in-cmake ?

or you mean I should include add_executable(TESTEXE test.cpp) before add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp a.h a.cpp? I am confused. Also I don't understand why TESTEXE should define the function main because TESTEXE and main have nothing to do with each other.

I don't know what you should do, because I don't know your intentions. You create TESTEXE executable, so you want to be able to run it (e.g. from the command line). What do you expect to happen when you run TESTEXE? E.g. if you want TESTEXE to execute lines under test function upon running, then just rename test to main. Or write main function (in the same file) which would call test function.

Yes, I want to be able to have % ./out/build/OURROJECT to run the top main file and % ./out/build/../TESTEXE to run the test.cpp. You mean I could just change test.cpp to main.cpp without the hassle of doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919957/how-can-i-build-two-executables-that-share-a-main-function-in-cmake ? It is okay to have 2 main files in a single project?

No, I do not ask you to rename a file. The error message is about functions defined in the file. Every executable should define a function named main. Your TESTEXE executable doesn't define a function named main, so the linker cannot determine which code should be executed when your executable will be run.

OHMYGOSH IT WORKS thank you so much for your help!
I did get a warning though ld: warning: reexported library with install name '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.1.dylib' found at '/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/18.1.6/lib/libunwind.1.0.dylib' couldn't be matched with any parent library and will be linked directly
nothing wrong... right?
